# Core Data: sorting before saving

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

I am adding to a simple entity, a list of names (from an array).
But before saving the entity, I would like them to be sorted. Please could someone be so kind as to tell me how to do this?

I've seen how to sort some fetched data, but I do not know how to do this. A written example would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSString *myTempString;

for (databaseMakerVC *aName in peoplesNames.theArray) {
    myTempString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", aName];

    peoplesNamesObject *newObject = [NSEntityDescription
                                     insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"peoplesNamesObject"
                                     inManagedObjectContext:context];
    newObject.aName = myTempString;
}


    // *** Do the sorting here!? ***


// Save the context
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
```

Comment: take a look at :
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it

Comment: Why do you need to sort before saving? Any reasons? Thanks.

Comment: as far as i know, you dont gain any performance improvement if you sort before saving.  That doesnt mean that you cannot sort the items for other reasons.

Comment: @Flex_Addicted  because Core Data is saving them in the entity in a random fashion. I want them in a particular order.

Comment: @luxsypher the page is just discussing sorting an array. My problem is the data is added to the entity jumbled. (Even thought the source array is ordered!)

Answer (score 2):

```
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                                   entityForName:@"peoplesNamesObject" inManagedObjectContext:context];

 [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


     NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"aName" ascending:YES]; 

        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]; 

        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors]; 

        NSError *error;


       NSArray *array=[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

This will work

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Just add a sort descriptor after you insert the object

The `sortDescriptorWithKey` looks for a key in the array. In a array I created I assigned a key to "createdDate" and sorted it by that. So you would assign a key of "name" and use the code below

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort=[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
[peoplesNames.theArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

Comment: BigT, *please* could you write that code, in context with my code above?